# Avoiding Duplicate in list in html list by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a list in HTML which is printing by the values comign from Json. I have a button in html

```
 <button onclick="printJsonList()">CLICK</button>
```

which runs this Javascript

```
function printJsonList(){
    console.log(ctNameKeep);
            var ctList = []; var ctRight = [];
            var ctNameKeep = [];
            var $tBody = $("#La");
            var $rbody = $("#accordian");

            $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/n0u2o' , function (data) {
                    data.forEach((CTLIST) => {
                        if(ctNameKeep.includes(CTLIST.ct)){
                            return ;
                        }
                        else {
                   ctNameKeep.push(CTLIST.ct);
                        $tBody.append(`<li class="list-group-item" id="rl">
                        <span id="nameOfCt">${CTLIST.ct}</span>
                                <a href="#${CTLIST.ct}" class="btn btn-danger show" data-toggle="collapse">View More</a>

                         <div id="${CTLIST.ct}" class="collapse valueDiv">
                              <label>TTS</label> <input id="tts" type="text" value="${CTLIST.tts}"><br>
                              <label>Topic Level</label> <input id="topic_level" type="text" value="${CTLIST.topic_level}"><br> 
                              <label>TimeOut</label> <input id="timeout" type="text" value="${CTLIST.timeout}"><br>
                                <label>To be shown individually</label> <input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.to_be_shown_individually && 'checked')}> <br>
                              <label>check for geometry</label><input id="check_for_geometry" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.check_for_geometry && 'checked')}><br>
                              <label>check_for_image_labelling</label> <input id="check_for_image_labelling" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.check_for_image_labelling && 'checked')}> <br>         
                     </div>        

                        </li>`);
                    } //else 
                    });
            })
            console.log(ctNameKeep)
    }
```

I am storing the name of ct in an array and checking if ctNameKeep array includes that name just avoid printing that lists item. Its working good on first click of button. But when i click button again it prints list again . But what i want is if user click button second or third time the list having same name ct in html list array should not print. It does not matter how many time funciton run. The problem I am facing is I want to do all this in a function nothing can be global. Please Give any possible solution or replacement.

[image: Button clinked first time]

[image: Button clicked again]

Comment: Inside the loop you fixed the id atribute ,the id is unique .but in your case it will duplicate

Comment: So is there any option to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

#### By binding a function with some params

Consider having in a perfect world:

```
function printJsonList(ctNameKeep){
  someajaxcall(function(something){
    ctNameKeep.push(something)
  })
}
```

Then you can create

`const printJsonList2 = printJsonList.bind(null, [])`

Any call to `printJsonList2` will actually call `printJsonList([])`.

An array being referenced you can modify it to your taste.

Thus `<button onclick="printJsonList2()"></button>`

#### By "component"

It is trendy to make some components.

You could make one responsible of handling your button.

```
const myBtn = ((btn => {
  let ctNameKeep = [] // ctNameKeep not global anymore
  function printJsonList(){ctNameKeep.push('..')}
  btn.addEventListener('click', printJsonList)
  return {somemethodsForYourComponent} // you don't need this though
})(document.querySelector('button'))
```

---

```js
const printJsonList = (function (ctNameKeep) {
  ctNameKeep.push(String.fromCharCode(65+Math.floor(Math.random()*26)))
  console.log('ctNameKeep', ctNameKeep)
}).bind(null, [])

;(btn => {
  let ctNameKeep = []
  function printJsonList () {
    ctNameKeep.push(String.fromCharCode(65+Math.floor(Math.random()*26)))
    console.log('anotherone', ctNameKeep)
  }

  btn.addEventListener('click', printJsonList)
})(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1])
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick="printJsonList()">clickbind</button>
<button>clickcomp</button>
</div>
```